# What Query should i use in Hibernate to fetch POJO?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, session, jpa

I learnt Hibernate and used it to reduce my Java code to a vast extent and also able
 to reduce the time spent for DB's. Now what type of query should i use to finish my
 operations for getting a DB list to be displayed, to update and delete.

**My code for deletion is**

```
String newToken = "DELETEUSER";
if(!TokenManager.checkRoleToken(newToken)){
    return;
}
Session session = Main.getSession(); //calling the main method to get sesion 
Leavetable table = new Leavetable; // intialisation of object table
try{
    Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
    table = session.createQuery();
    session.delete(table); // deletion of the object and its properties  from selected leaveID
    tr.commit();            
}
finally{
    session.close();
}
```

**My code for Db updation**

```
public void updateLeaveTable( Leavetable leave ) {
    String newToken = "ADDUSER";
    if( !TokenManager.checkRoleToken( newToken ) ) {
        return;
    }
    Session session = Main.getSession(); // calling the main method to get
                                         // session
    try {
        session = Main.getSession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate( leave ); // here without query the table gets
                                       // updated How?
        tr.commit();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

What type of query should I follow. My final task before going into project. When I
know this will start my life as a developer. Any suggestions Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a HQL query? Well, a typical query on your `Leavetable` entity would looks like this:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Leavetable t where t.someField = :value");
q.setParameter("value", foo);
List<Leavetable> results = q.list();
```

---

However, if you just want to retrieve an entity by identifier, see [`Session#load()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#load(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable)) or [`Session#get()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29). I don't want to make things too much confusing but while both methods are similar, there is an important difference between both of them. Quoting the [Hibernate Forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2387456):

> #### Retrieving objects by identifier
>
> The following Hibernate code snippet
>   retrieves a User object from the
>   database:
>
> ```
> User user = (User) session.get(User.class, userID);
> ```
>
> The `get()` method is special because
>   the identifier uniquely identifies a
>   single instance of a class. Hence it’s
>   common for applications to use the
>   identifier as a convenient handle to a
>   persistent object. Retrieval by
>   identifier can use the cache when
>   retrieving an object, avoiding a
>   database hit if the object is already
>   cached. Hibernate also provides a
>   `load()` method:
>
> ```
> User user = (User) session.load(User.class, userID);
> ```
>
> The load() method is older; get() was
>   added to Hibernate’s API due to user
>   request. The difference is trivial:
>
> If `load()` can’t find the object in
>   the cache or database, an exception is
>   thrown. The load() method never
>   returns null. The `get()` method
>   returns `null` if the object can’t be
>   found.
>
> The `load()` method may return a proxy
>   instead of a real persistent instance.
>   A proxy is a placeholder that triggers
>   the loading of the real object when
>   it’s accessed for the first time; we
>   discuss proxies later in this section.
>   On the other hand, `get()` never
>   returns a proxy.
>
> **Choosing between `get()` and `load()`
>   is easy:** If you’re certain the
>   persistent object exists, and
>   nonexistence would be considered
>   exceptional, `load()` is a good
>   option. If you aren’t certain there is
>   a persistent instance with the given
>   identifier, use `get()` and test the
>   return value to see if it’s null.
>   Using `load()` has a further
>   implication: The application may
>   retrieve a valid reference (a proxy)
>   to a persistent instance without
>   hitting the database to retrieve its
>   persistent state. So `load()` might
>   not throw an exception when it doesn’t
>   find the persistent object in the
>   cache or database; the exception would
>   be thrown later, when the proxy is
>   accessed.
>
> Of course, retrieving an object by
>   identifier isn’t as flexible as using
>   arbitrary queries.

See also the Hibernate Documentation (links below).

#### Reference

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [10.3. Loading an object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-loading)
  - [Chapter 14. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: @pascal thanks a lot, can i write my Hql query like this
Query q = session.createQuery("from Leavetable t where t.leaveID = :id");
q.setParameter("id", ...); what does that foo denote hear

Comment: @pascal For updation i dont need a query itseems, hibernate does that for me. session.saveOrUpdate( leave ). am i right

Comment: @Code That foo was just a random example because I don't know what a Leavetable looks like :) But I have added more details about the way to retrieve an object by its identifier since I understand now that this might have been your initial intention (vs "generic" query).

Comment: @thanks a lot for making me understand the two methods and their difference.

Comment: @ya i found it,foo is the id value which am passing through my method.

Comment: @Code `foo` is the variable holding the value that is set in the `:value` "named parameter" in the hql query.

Comment: @pascal thank you very much. I will keep you all as my mentors and definitely will succeed. Thank you very much for your kind support.